# Label text is not properly displayed in Xamarin Android and Windows app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a text which I have formatted in the required format. But it's not exactly the same.

My Actual string for text is:

[image]

But display is different.

[image]

I am facing the same issue in windows and android both apps. Somewhere on the internet its mentioned that its related to the fonts. But I am not able to fix it.

Comment: You asked the same question a week ago and received an answer.  Please do not ask the same question multiple times.

Comment: Sorry, But I couldn't solve my issue with the given solution. Could you please help

Comment: Then post a comment on the original question asking for more help.  And "I couldn't solve my issue" is not a helpful explanation.  What specifically did you try, what errors or problems did you encounter, etc?